# Why does this happen when I create goroutine through the loop?

Tags: go, goroutine

Please help me.
I have block codes, It uses iteration to get the elements of the map, and use this element to create a listener on a port on a Linux machine, But Its execution exceeded my expectations.
code show as below:

```
var srvs = map[string]struct {
  id       int
  timezone string
  connCfg  string
  conn     net.Conn
}{"BrazilEastSrv": {id: 1, timezone: "Brazil/East", connCfg: "127.0.0.1:9007"},
  "AustraliaDarwinSrv": {id: 2, timezone: "Australia/Darwin", connCfg: "127.0.0.1:9008"}}

var ch1 = make(chan int, 2)

func main() {
  for k, srv := range srvs {
    go func() {
      if ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", srv.connCfg); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("%s : %s conn failed,", k, srv.connCfg))
      } else {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s created, port:%s listened.", k, srv.connCfg[:9], srv.connCfg[10:]))
        if conn, err := ln.Accept(); err != nil {
          log.Fatal(srv.connCfg, " conn create fatal, errmsg=", err)
        } else {
          srv.conn = conn
          defer srv.conn.Close()
          log.Println("Accepted an access request from cli:", srv.conn.RemoteAddr(), ".")
          handleMsg(srv)
        }
      }
    }()
  }
  var brazilEastSrv, australiaDarwinSrv = <-ch1
  log.Println(brazilEastSrv, australiaDarwinSrv)
}
```

output:

```
2017/12/07 11:45:48 AustraliaDarwinSrv:127.0.0.1 created, port:9008 listened.
2017/12/07 11:45:48 AustraliaDarwinSrv : 127.0.0.1:9008 conn failed,
exit status 1
```

Seen from the output content. It uses the last element of the iteration and reuses this element, Why does it have this problem?

But when I make some changes：

```
var srvs = map[string]struct {
  id       int
  timezone string
  connCfg  string
  conn     net.Conn
}{"BrazilEastSrv": {id: 1, timezone: "Brazil/East", connCfg: "127.0.0.1:9007"},
  "AustraliaDarwinSrv": {id: 2, timezone: "Australia/Darwin", connCfg: "127.0.0.1:9008"}}

var ch1 = make(chan int, 2)

func main() {
  for k, srv := range srvs {
    go func(srv struct {                                                                                                                                                                   
      id       int
      timezone string
      connCfg  string
      conn     net.Conn
    }) {
      //go func() {
      if ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", srv.connCfg); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("%s : %s conn failed,", k, srv.connCfg))
      } else {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s created, port:%s listened.", k, srv.connCfg[:9], srv.connCfg[10:]))
        if conn, err := ln.Accept(); err != nil {
          log.Fatal(srv.connCfg, " conn create fatal, errmsg=", err)
        } else {
          srv.conn = conn
          defer srv.conn.Close()
          log.Println("Accepted an access request from cli:", srv.conn.RemoteAddr(), ".")
          handleMsg(srv)
        }
      }
      //}()
    }(srv)
  }
  var brazilEastSrv, australiaDarwinSrv = <-ch1
  log.Println(brazilEastSrv, australiaDarwinSrv)
}
```

It behaves in line with my expectations, what caused that difference? Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines.

Comment: Sorry, I should read the golang official documentation carefully to avoid asking such stupid questions, Thanks again for your comments

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, your goroutine uses the variable `srv` (and `k`) which changes with each iteration of the loop, so you don't know what value your goroutine will see when it is executing. In the second version, you're passing `srv` as an argument to the goroutine, so the variable `srv` within the goroutine is no longer the same variable that is used in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, this solves my problem, but if I use `var srv1 = srv` on the first line of the loop and use it in the goroutine, I can solve the problem by not passing the parameter to the goroutine and why ? What is the difference between it and the first version?

Comment: Sorry, I should read the golang official documentation carefully to avoid asking such stupid questions, Thanks again for your comments.